# I accidentally clicked something, and viewport is not showing color

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I Think I accidentally clicked something an viewport is showing only gray. Materials are still colored but the color doesn't show up, please help

EDIT: My problem here was, that i Clicked Solid view in 3D Viewport. It is the four buttons next to X-ray mode.

Comment: hello, a screenshot would help to understand

Comment: read this part of the manual https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/shading.html